# How to prevent the repetitive execution of a function in an addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to start an animation when the user's cursor is over an HTML element that contains multiple elements inside. Taking the following code as reference:

```
<div ref={exampleReference}>
  <img src='...' />
  <div>
    <h1> Some text <h1/>
    <p> Lorem ipsum etc. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Next.js and React, so the element targets is defined with useRef(). Therefore, the event listener results in:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    exampleReference.current.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {...} 
});
```

The event that this element is listening to is `mouseover`. It works but everytime I move the cursor between container elements: `<img>`, `<h1>` or `<p>`,  the event listener executes the callback function, say from `<img>` to `<h1>`.

So, how can I prevent the function from executing every time that the user's cursor position change between the main `div` container elements? In other words, I only want the animtaed function to be executed once the cursor is insede of the main `div` container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the second parameter for the `useEffect`, namely, the dependency array.

Then the call will be something like this

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        exampleReference.current.adedEventListener("mouseover", () => {...} 
    },[exampleReference.current]); // this one here
```

You can read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`mouseenter` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) instead of a `mouseover` event.

Comment: I tried `mouseenter` but it results in almost the same. When I move the cursor slowly, between the elements it doesn't execute the function but it does when I move it faster.